# getting exception is sending JMS message through rabbitmq-jms-1.6.0

Tags: rabbitmq

I am getting below exception some times while sending message to rabbitmq using rabbitms-jms-1.6.0 client. Most of the times it works.

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-ha-1.rabbitmq-ha-discovery.infra.svc.cluster.local' of durable queue 'xxxx' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:209) [amqp-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:338) [amqp-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:686) [amqp-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:668) [amqp-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:658) [amqp-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicPublish(AutorecoveringChannel.java:192) [amqp-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at
```